# Query Removes Date Values

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

```
=filter(query(Vendors!$A$3:$M,"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M",1),Vendors!$L$3:$L = "Invited",Vendors!$I$3:$I - Vendors!$G$3:$G <=$F$6)
```

I have the above formula that will query and return the results.  However in all date columns I get a random number string instead of the date being referenced.

[Query Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsUD1.png)
I tried enabling data validation in one column to fromat as date.

Any advice on how to get the query to return the date instead of this number string? All of the other columns return text and numbers correctly.

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem with the shortest formula, provide some sample data and a link to a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are date numbers. Format those columns as dates from the sheet menu.

Answer (score 0):

The *query* (as you specify) would return the date instead of the number string it you appropriately added a format clause. *Exactly* what that would be cannot be deduced from the little information you have provided.